# Create a PSPICE library from a schematic

Tags: spice, pspice, orcad

I need to simulate a part in OrCad PSpice, which doesn't have a pspice model anywhere. However, manufacturer have provided a gate level design of the IC on the datasheet. Using which I have constructed the part using generic logic symbols. It works fine, however, I wish to associate this entire schematic I created with a schematic symbol, so that I can place it on other schematics or other designs as if it was a regular pspice component.

I would imagine that there should be a way to place input and output ports to the schematic, then draw a model, and associate pins on the drawing with the ports on the schematic.

Is it possible to do something along the lines of this, and if so, how?

Comment: You'll have to search for the available documentation (`F1`, the built-in help) about hierarchical schematics, or extracting a netlist from your schematic to be used as a subcircuit.

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen yes, this kind of works. I didn't notice that built in help menu was useful, they usually are not. But this is not exactly what I was looking for. Hierarchical blocks and regular parts look different, and behave different. I am looking to be able to associate a regular model I would draw with the schematic.

Comment: "*or extracting a netlist from your schematic to be used as a subcircuit*" -- this is what you need then.